# Confirm dialog and how to control it in code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, code-behind, scriptmanager

When I load page I load this script:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(),
                              "question",
                              "<script type = 'text/javascript'>if(confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?')) return true; else return false;</script>",
                              false);
```

I don't know how to handle when user click on **yes** to do something in code behind and when click on **no** to do some other thing?
How to handle this click in code behind?

Answer (score 0):

if you are returning true/false, then in the code behind you will only get true.
To get values for false also you will have to create another function.

The best method that i like is setting the value of the return parameter in hiddenfield. And the getting this variable in codebehind and the working accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have already have code for that.
You can only call javascript functions on Yes or NO. But Javascript function can call codebehind webmethods using Ajax.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(),
                              "question",
                              "<script type = 'text/javascript'>if(confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?')){[Call Function for Yes]} else{ [Call Function for No or Cancel];}</script>",
                              false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than the WebMethods technique, you also have an option of using the **__doPostBack** method to hit code-behind from your javascript code. More info on its usage at http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function.all, http://dopostback.net/.

A limitation of using WebMethods is, since they are always static, your non-static fields, methods, and controls won't be accessible inside them. http://forums.asp.net/t/1531113.aspx/1.